# Execute shell script from its folder location and not caller folder location?

Tags: php, linux, shell

i have one problem in shell script. I have an apache2 web server in `/var/www`. I have `index.php` and its php code is:

`<?php
  system('sh /minecraft/server1/starter1.sh', $retval);
?>`

Code of `starter1.sh`:

`sudo -i screen -d -m -S Server1 java -Xmx1G -jar /minecraft/server1/spigot.jar`

if i go in `/minecraft/server1/` and i execute `sh ./starter1.sh` the server starts properly, but when i call the script (`starter1.sh`) from the `index.php` (`/var/www`) the server seems to start in `/root/`. How can i call the starter (`/minecraft/server1/starter1.sh`) from the web page (`/var/www/html/index.php`) properly?

> If I did some wrong command please tell me but help me solve the problem

Comment: how do you figure out that your command is running normally and start in /root ??

Answer (score 0, accepted):

just change your script and add a cd /minecraft/server1/ before sudo [..]

edit: remove the -i after sudo

Comment: if you need to start it from that path becouse you need your saved file change Server1 java -Xmx1G -jar /minecraft/server1/spigot.jar to

Comment: oh sorry, i did'nt see that -i after sudo. it change your current pwd to the root's one. Try to avoid it:
sudo screen -d -m -S Server1 java -Xmx1G -jar /minecraft/server1/spigot.jar

Comment: Thank you, Roberto! This thing fixed my problem. Thanks again!

Answer (score 0):

You can change your working directory by using:
 chdir("current_directory/.../");

So the code should be:

```
<?php
  chdir("current_directory/.../");
  system('sh /minecraft/server1/starter1.sh', $retval);
?>
```